# On connected sets of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, connectedness, mean-value-theorem

> Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be an open and connected set. If $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ has partial derivatives equal to zero on every point of $U$, then $f$ is constant.

My idea to prove the result above is to fix $a := (a_1, \ldots, a_n)$, take an arbitrary point $b := (b_1, \ldots, b_n)$, create a chain of points that connect $a$ to $b$ and apply the following version of the Mean Value Theorem:

**(Theorem)** Let $U \subseteq \mathbb{R}^{n}$ be an open set and $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Suppose that $[a, a+v] \subseteq U$, where $v \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$, and $\partial_{v}f(x)$ exists for every $x \in (a, a+v)$. Then, there exists $\theta \in (0,1)$ such that $f(a+v) - f(a) = \partial_{v}f(a+ \theta v)$.

This seems to be the correct approach. However, for that to work, the chain of points that we take to connect $a$ and $b$ have to move only in the directions $e_1, \ldots, e_n$, one at a time. I know that a connected set in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is polygonally connected, but that doesn't say we can connect two points only through vectors of the form $v := te_i$. It makes sense intuitively, and it probably works, but I was unable to find any result about this. Is that correct?

Comment: What I think you are describing is path connectedness. However, it's now true that any connected subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is also path connected

Comment: @EduardoMagalhães no, connected by a collection of segments is what the OP means

Comment: $U$ is also connected by paths consisting of segments perpendicular to the coordinate axes - the usual proof applies, pick $x\in U$ and consider $\{y\in U : x \sim y\}$ where $x\sim y$ means that $x, y$ can be connected by such path, show its closed and open in $U$.

Comment: Not every connected set is path connected, but a connected **open** set in $\mathbb R^n$ is path connected and polygonally connected.

Comment: You don't need to move by segments perpendicular to axes by the way, your theorem is for any vector $v$

Comment: @Jakobian The MVT works for any $v$, but the result I'm trying to prove is the first one that I wrote, which only guarantees existence of partial derivatives. So I have to move through segments perpendicular to axes.

Comment: @Aeschylus The partial derivatives are continuous so the function is differentiable and the directional derivatives are given by $\partial_vf(x) = \nabla f(x) \cdot v = 0$ where $\nabla f$ is the gradient. If you want alternative approach, do it like how I mentioned in the comment about proving connectedness via paths perpendicular to the axes

Comment: @Jakobian That makes sense. I believe that also works. I'm still curious about moving along segments that are perpendicular to the axes though.

Comment: If you know how to prove that $U$ is polygonally connected, proving that its connected along segments perpendicular to the axes is proven the exact same way. I think it would be a good exercise for you to try it

Comment: @Jakobian I'll try that. Thank you!